# How to change dynamic attributes when simple product is selected

Tags: magento-1.9, products

Here is my problem.

I have a Magento website (CE 1.9.2.1) selling radiators. Each radiator is available in various sizes and the heat output etc is different for each size. When a size is selected via the configurable product I would like to show certain attributes for this size (simple product) in the description area.

I have a module setup (Best4Mage Configurable Products Simple Prices) that changes the description when a simple (size) is selected. I have edited my description.phtml code to the below (which includes a single attribute currently) but when the description changes (upon selection of a specific size) the attributes disappear:

```
 

$product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('reina_type');
if ($attribute)
{
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
}
?>

getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>


    __('Product Information') ?>

        helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
        Material: getAttributeText('reina_type'); ?>
```